# Why does Stack Exchange allow fake email addresses for registration?

Tags: support, asking-questions, spam, unregistered-users

I don't understand, Stack Exchange is a huge, spam-less site.

On the major part of the sites (not Stack Overflow though) anyone can post a question as a "guest" by just typing any email:

> [image]

By allowing fake email registration there will be a huge increase in spam generated here. So why does Stack Exchange still allow fake email for registration?

Comment: Define "fake email". How do you expect us to detect an email address is fake?

Comment: Additionally, given how well the community moderates content, can you explain what problem would be solved by disallowing such emails for registration?

Comment: @Oded Ask pcloud admins how to detect fake email?, they don't allow fake email while registration.

Comment: You brought it up, so I am asking you ;) - but the main question I have, was not answered: what problem would this solve? What problem are you seeing with fake emails for registrations that you think disallowing them would solve?

Comment: @Oded spam problems will get solved, i already mentioned in the question.

Comment: Um. What spam problems? Our spam is taken care of pretty quickly by the community. As you noted the sites are "spam less".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/458741; tl;dr it's impossible to "validate" an e-mail address in code. More generally, it's impossible to validate something that exists without actually checking that it exists.

Comment: @Oded "How do you expect us to detect an email address is fake": By confirming the email address is valid as part of the registration process (like many other websites do as part of their registration process) - send a confirmation email and require verification.

Comment: @DavidPostill - doesn't really work all that well when we support OpenId. We *do* the confirmation dance with the Stack Exchange OpenId provider though. Still - my main point issue is that the OP is asking us to solve a problem we don't have because other people do have it.

Comment: In your question you state that the sites spam-less and then you tell there is a problem? I don't follow you. What is the problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: This makes sense. When you take away being able to register from spammer-liked emails such as Gmail, Yahoo, AOL and Hotmail, only spammers will have email addresses from those domains

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you actually suggest here is that Stack Overflow will require the user to verify the email before he/she can post.

This is just an extra step that will make it harder for ordinary people to post, while not making the spammers' life even a bit harder. I'm 100% sure they can use, and are using, real email addresses and can verify them just as any other (real) user.

All in all, just a pointless barrier that should not exist in the first place, and I'm glad it really doesn't exist.